# My multilayer canvas scrolls too slowly using the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a multilayered canvas. The images inside can be big so they overflow the dimensions of the , and I have to scroll (and I want that it works so). I draw different images in each layer but I want their relative position fixed, so I have to scroll all the canvas together: when I scroll the first one I want they all to scroll.

The problem is that it scrolls very slowly. When I click on the arrows down/up it scrolls only some pixel. When I keep the mouse down on an arrow it scroll few pixels/second. When I click on the scrollbar, outside the bar, it make a jump of only 50-100 pixels. But if I drag the bar it move normally (fast).

My `html`:

```
<div style='display:inline-block; width:100%; position:relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;'>
    <div id='canvas1' class='canvas canvas_map' style='overflow:scroll; background-color: lightgrey; z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:133px; top:0px;'></div>
    <div id='canvas2' class='canvas canvas_map' style='overflow:scroll; z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:133px; top:0px;'></div>
    [...]
    <div id='canvas12' class='canvas canvas_map' style='overflow:scroll; z-index: 12; position:absolute; left:133px; top:0px;'></div>
    <div id='canvas13' draggable='true' class='canvas canvas_map' style='overflow:scroll; cursor: crosshair; z-index: 13; position:absolute; left:133px; top:0px;'></div>
</div>
```

My `javascript`:

```
var canvas_list=document.getElementsByClassName('canvas_map');
document.getElementById('canvas13').addEventListener(
    'scroll', function() {
    var scroll_x = document.getElementById('canvas13').scrollLeft;
    var scroll_y = document.getElementById('canvas13').scrollTop;
    for (var i=0; i<canvas_list.length; i++) {
        canvas_list[i].scrollLeft=scroll_x;
        canvas_list[i].scrollTop=scroll_y;
    };
});
```

PS: I'm using [Raphael library](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) for drawing the images:

```
var paper_map1 = Raphael(canvas1, '100%', '100%');
[...]
```

PS2: most canvas are empty, the other have 1-2 light images, so it shouldn't be a memory problem.

Comment: You may be better of doing a mouse drag zoom / touch pinch pan zoom / keyboard pan zoom and thus not need the ugly scrollbars and providing a much more intuitive interface than standard scrollbars

Comment: I already use mouse drag for move image on the canvas so that function is not avaible for pan (btw I don't want to zoom my image). I don't want to use keyboard command.